# Wordpress and PHP Version Upgrade issue

Tags: php, themes

I am running PHP Version 5.6 on my Ubuntu 14.04 Server.

```
/home/ubuntu# php -v
PHP 5.6.36-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

But when I am activating a theme I am getting below error

> Your server's PHP version (5.5.9-1ubuntu4.24) is not supported.
>
> This version is old, insecure and slow. Please update it as soon as
>   possible.

Any insights why this is happening?

Comment: I see an issue with the theme you try to activate, not with WordPress.

Comment: Are you sure that your site is using 5.6? Just because you installed it doesn't mean your web server is using it, afterall you can have 1 version for CLI and another for WWW, and multiple versions installed in parallel

Comment: Yes so CLI is using 5.6 now and web server is still using the older how to make apache2 web server point to newer version?

Answer (score 1):

The version of PHP used in the cli and your web server can vary depending upon your hosting and/or Apache configuration. Obviously, you are checking the command line interface version.

You can use your cPanel to determine what versions of PHP Apache is using, you can install a PHPinfo type plug that shows the standard phpinfo() output in the WP admin area, or you can create a simple phpinfo() page outside of WordPress.

Comment: Yes the PHP.ini file that loaded has version PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.24 how do I change this so that correct php.ini file will load for version 5.6

Comment: Afraid you'll have to work with your hosting provider to get that information. I don't how they have cPannel configured.